# Creating PDF with data source

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I've been tasked with creating an editable PDF (or similar off-line accessible) form with certain fields (dropdown lists and the like) prepopulated with data. Based on what is selected in the dropdowns, other text fields will be populated with associated data.

Short of creating a Windows Form with 100+ different fields, is there software that has this capability? I know I can't be the only one with a task like this, but having Googled and searched up and down SO I've drawn a blank.

I felt this was the most appropriate exchange to post this in; apologies if I am mistaken.

---

EDIT

I have access to Acrobat Pro 7 at work, but it seems unable to do what I described above. Do I need a newer version of Acrobat to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using InfoPath? It has basically been designed for this purpose and can interact with external data sources (e.g. SharePoint / databases). You can then convert the InfoPath form to PDF if needed, either using your own code or using  third party product such as the [PDF Converter for SharePoint](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/batch-print-infopath-forms-using-pdf.html)

I worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a professional job, you need to use the right tool (Adobe Acrobat Pro):

http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro.html

Comment: Probably should have mentioned that I have access to Acrobat Professional 7 at work. I have been unable to figure out how to populate fields with existing data (from an external data source). Do I need a newer version of Acrobat Pro?

Comment: What is the external data source?